# Python: keep getting an error "unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

So I have been given a python booklet to follow from my first GCSE computer science lesson. and one tasks asks me to improve the efficiency of this code using and, or and not operators:

```
one=int(input("Please Enter Number 1:"))
two=int(input("Please Enter Number 2:"))
three=int(input("Please Enter Number 3:"))
    if(one==two):
        if(two==three):
           print ("SNAP!")
    else:
        print ("The Do not all match")
    else:
        print("They do not all match")
```

however I have no knowladge of aand, or and not operators. I have tried to find the correct syntax to use.

I then tried to use this code:

```
one=int(input("Please Enter Number 1:"))
two=int(input("Please Enter Number 2:"))
three=int(input("Please Enter Number 3:"))

    if one==two and two==three:
        print ("SNAP!")
    else:
        print ("The Do not all match")
    else:
        print("They do not all match")
```

but got the error message "unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Im a bit stuck now because I have no clue to what that is supposed to mean, i know its probably a simple fix but if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: 1) Decrese the indention of line four and following by one level. 2) Only use one `else` clause.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have two `else` blocks together, just remove one `else` and line up your code block with the input:

```
one = int(input("Please Enter Number 1:"))
two = int(input("Please Enter Number 2:"))
three = int(input("Please Enter Number 3:")) 

if one == two and two == three: 
    print ("SNAP!")
else:                               
    print("They do not all match")
```

Comment: Wasn't me. The other answer that seems to have gone now was not helpful at all -- Yours is fine and hopefully useful :)

Comment: Thank you this worked, the book from the exam board was telling me to use 2 'else' I will notify my school!

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion from a noobie.

```
if one==two==three:
    print('SNAP!')
elif len(set([one,two,three]))==3:
    print('All three are different')
else:
    print('They do not all match')
```